# Proving equality involving integral over Gaussian kernels

Tags: integration

In the paper "[Bandwidth Selection: Classical or Plug-In?](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1018031201)" by C.R. Loader on pp. 419-420, the following equality appears (slightly rewritten):

$$ \frac{1}{n^2k^6} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi''\left( \frac{X_i - x}{k} \right) \phi''\left(\frac{X_j - x}{k}\right) = \frac{1}{n^2(\sqrt{2}k)^5} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \phi^{(4)} \left( \frac{X_i - X_j}{\sqrt{2}k} \right)$$

where $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$. However, I am struggling to figure out how to begin to prove this to myself. **Could someone help me see why the equality holds holds?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $A$ instead of $X_i/k$, $B$ instead of $X_j/k$, and $y$ instead of $x/k$, so the (now missing) $dx$ in the integral on the LHS is $k\; dy$, it is enough to show:
$$
\int_{\Bbb R}\phi''(A-y)\phi''(B-y)\; dy
=
\phi^{(IV)}(A-B)\ .
$$
To see this, we start with
$$
\int_{\Bbb R}\phi(A-y)\phi(B-y)\; dy
=
\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\phi(A-B)\ ,
$$
then build derivatives twice w.r.t. $A$, then twice w.r.t. $B$.